# http://xxxxx.com/username on Java Servlet environment(GAE/J) without JSP

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, servlets

I want to develop a website such as

http://xxxxx.com/username (like facebook URL style)
on Java Servlet environment(GAE/J), and do not want to use JSP stuff, since I develop a rich html5 site with JQuery.

I've already done the client structure with HTML5 framework and do not want to start with JSP stuff from a scratch.

I could control the URI request via web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SubDirRouter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myproject.SubDirRouter</servlet-class>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SubDirRouter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is it possible to 'foward' not 'redirect'(since http://xxxxx.com/username URL disappears) to a member.html (HTML5 application) file from the SubDirRouter servlet?

OR

simply map url-pattern-> /* to a member.html file ??

and if it's possible please show me how. A sample code or a site containing that would be appreciated.

Thank you. Again, a last option to me is to use JSP and discard html.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can "forward" internally via [`getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29):

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/yourHtm5page.html").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Thank you Peter.  I am trying this. 'code'if (userID.equals("username.html"))
  {
  } else
  {
   ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
   try
   {
    sc.getRequestDispatcher("/username.html").forward(req, resp);
   } catch (ServletException e)
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }'code'

Answer (score 0):

Well,

usually an temp-redirect (307) should NOT change the original request-url (/username in your case).

Comment: I just ask for an alternative method for HTML5 implement rather than JSP style. Thank you.

Comment: SubDirRouter isn't JSP-Style. SubDirRouter is Servlet-style. Are you looking for an alternate for Servlet-Style?

Comment: Yes, I know. The only method I can think of is that to map /* subdomain to SubDireRouter Servlet, then try to forward a html file.